# Counting every line and adding to the end of each line in a csv

Tags: ruby

What I want to do is count how many @ are in each row and put this value into a total field at the end.

I mean it sort of works, but its only adding the value of the last line it counts.

My Csv

```
Header,Header,Header
Info@,Info,Info
Info,Info@@,Info
Info,Info,Info@@@
```

My Code

```
require "csv"
table = CSV.read("my_test.csv", {
  headers: true,
  col_sep: ","
})

File.readlines('my_test.csv').each do |line| 
  table.each do |row|
    at_count = line.count('@')
    row["Total"] = at_count
  end
end

CSV.open("my_test.csv", "w") do |f|
  f << table.headers
  table.each { | row | f << row }
end
```

Current Result

```
Header,Header,Header,Total
Info@,Info,Info,3
Info,Info@@,Info,3
Info,Info,Info@@@,3
```

Comment: Don't forget Ruby allows you to omit the `{ ... }` braces on hashes if that hash is the last argument. It reduces the amount of clutter in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `File.readlines`; CSV already read it.

```
require "csv"
table = CSV.read("test.csv", { headers: true}) #just shorter

table.each do |row |  #no readlines
  at_count = row.to_s.count('@')  # note the to_s
  row["Total"] = at_count
end


CSV.open("my_test.csv", "w") do |f |
  f << table.headers
  table.each { | row | f << row}
end
```

Comment: Do you have to update the headers manually when introducing a new column?

Comment: Why do I need to convert it to a string, I thought that it was already being read in as one. What would be the best way to count a column instead of row ? Eventually the header will get removed as it will all get fed into logstash

Comment: `IO.write('my_test.csv', table)` should work as well.

Comment: @Pokecallem it is not a string, it's a `CSV::row` object. If the headers are unique then you can access columns like this: `p table["Header1"]`

Comment: @Pokecallum `row.to_s` joins the fields in that row to a single string using the delimiter given by `col_sep`. You could also use something like `row.fields.sum { |f| f.count('@') }` – that would [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) the number of `@`'s in each field without incorporating delimiters and quotes (although it doesn't matter in this case).